# Natural sorting to sort columns of a dataframe by column name

Tags: r, sorting, natural-sort

I would like to arrange the columns of a dataframe by the column names. Is it possible to do this using natural sorting?

My columns are currently arranged numerically across the data from:

> Blockquote

```
#   A1 A10 A11 A12 A2 A3 A4 ...
# 1 
# 2 
# .
# .
# .
```

I would like to rearrange the columns so that they are arranged by natural sorting as below:

```
#   A1 A2 A3 A4 A10 A11 A12 ...
# 1 
# 2 
# .
# .
# .
```

Please note that my datasets are huge with hundreds of columns so the process needs to be automated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mixedsort` in the `gtools` package does exactly this.

```
library(gtools)
CNames = c("A1", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A2", "A3", "A4")
mixedsort(CNames)
[1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A10" "A11" "A12"
```

Of course, to rearrange your data.frame, you want something like

```
df = df[,mixedsort(colnames(df))]
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can achieve natural sorting in R using the gtools package:**

```
install.packages('gtools')
library(gtools)
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(A1=seq(1:10), A10=seq(1:10), A11=seq(1:10), A12=seq(1:10), A2=seq(1:10), A3=seq(1:10), A4=seq(1:10))
```

[image]

```
df[,mixedsort(names(df))]
```

[image]